# Updating JList by pressing button

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

first of all I will introduce what I am trying to do. This is an assignment in university we are making Hotel booking system with JAVA. To go straight to the point, all I need to know is how to update JList when I press button.

```
    listModel = new DefaultListModel<Hotel>();
      bookingList = new JList(listModel);
class MouseAdapterMod extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource() == searchButton){
     for(lists.getRoomsList() p : lists.getRoomsList())
     {
        listModel.addElement(p);
     }
     bookingList.setModel(listModel);
  }
```

In this GUI class I have instance variable (lists) of Hotel class, in Hotel class there are methods

```
    public ArrayList<Rooms> getRoomsList()
   {
      return roomsList.getListRooms();
   }
   public ArrayList<Suite> getSuitesList()
   {
      return roomsList.getListSuites();
   }
```

this returns whole ArrayList of Room class objects and also ArrayList of Suite class.
QUESTION would be is how to show whole ArrayList of Rooms when I press button, in other words how to update JList which consists of objects, by pressing button?
I hope I explained alright.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-each loop is wrong. Try this and see:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource().equals(searchButton)){
     ArrayList<Rooms> rooms = lists.getRoomsList();
     for(Rooms r : rooms) {
        listModel.addElement(r);
     }
     bookingList.setModel(listModel);
  }
}
```

This still looks sorta messy to me though. A more appropriate approach would be to set an event handler on the `searchButton`, to populate the `JList` when `searchButton` is clicked.

Also, are `Rooms` and `Suites` sub classes of `Hotel`? If not, you'll have to create `listModel` like this (for rooms):

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel<Rooms>();
```

Comment: Yea, there is a lot of mess, but I just started JAVA, like 3 months ago, I am fresh. By the way, thank you!!! Your code is working.